# Dynamic url to setup.exe in clickonce

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have an .NET application developed in .NET 4.0. Our clients are having web server at there own office where clickonce application is hosted so clickonce url can't be fixed as web server's machine name or IP address is different by each client.

Also to install prerequisites like .NET 4.0, VC++ etc setup.exe is needs to be downloaded and executed but setup.exe needs `-url` arguments set to URL where ClickOnce application is hosted (in my case its web server of every client)

So my question is how I can set `-url` to client's local web server where clickonce application is hosted?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the 'url' of your clickonce bootstrapper by passing the '/url' parameter as shown below.

```
setup.exe /url=http://serverhostname/
```

Note: the above command will only update the URL, not launch the setup. To launch you must open setup.exe without any parameters.